# Error on dpkg -L Command Result

Tags: dpkg

My `dpkg -L *` gives me this result:

```
Package `20140123_002246.mp4' is not installed.

Package `20140123_002246.mpg' is not installed.

Package `anu' is not installed.

Package `anu.cpp' is not installed.

Package `anu.sh' is not installed.

Package `anu.zip' is not installed.

Package `aplikasi' is not installed.

Package `aplikasi.tar.gz' is not installed.

Package `archives.tar.gz' is not installed.

Package `compizconfig.png' is not installed.

dpkg-query: error: package name in specifier 'Daurah Tegar di Atas Sunnah di Masa Fitnah - Al Ustadz Muhammad Umar As Sewed - Sesi 1.MP3' is illegal: character ` ' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
```

It is abnormal. I don't know how this could be happended. How to fix this? Thank you.

PS: as a comparison, my normal dpkg -L result is something like this:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/dhcp3-server
/usr/share/doc/dhcp3-server/copyright
/usr/share/doc/dhcp3-server/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/dhcp3-server/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Comment: Try to apply `dpkg -L` command to a package not files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first command is going through ALL files in your current directory, and `dpkg` is treating them as package names. This is because bash resolves the `*` to mean all files or directories in the current directory. In place of the `*`, you'll want to specify a package name.